# Zoom option is not locating the marked place when clicking the Marker

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have located 32 locations(districts) in a state using marker option using Google map API (javascript). Also I am trying to zoom the location(district) by clicking the marker. But when I clicked the marker it is **not zooming** the exact **location(district)** which I marked. Please help me by giving solution.

**I have posted my code below:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>marker</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
   
 </head>
  <body>
   <div id="map" style="width: 1366px; height: 700px;"></div> 
   <script>
 
     var minZoomLevel = 7;
     
    function initMap() {
      var myLatlng = {
       lat: 11.127123,
       lng: 78.656894
      };

      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
       zoom: minZoomLevel,
       center: myLatlng,
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
      });

      var emptyStyles = [{
       featureType: "all",
       elementType: "labels",
       stylers: [{
        visibility: "off"
       }]
      }];

      map.setOptions({
       styles: emptyStyles
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
       if (map.getZoom() < minZoomLevel) map.setZoom(minZoomLevel);
      });


      var districts = new Array("Namakkal", "Madurai", "Perambalur", "The Nilgiris", "Ariyalur", "Karur", "Theni", "Chennai", "Kancheepuram", "Vellore", "Thiruvallur", "Villupuram", "Coimbatore", "Tirunelveli", "Tiruchirappalli", "Cuddalore", "Tiruppur", "Tiruvannamalai", "Thanjavur", "Erode", "Dindigul", "Virudhunagar", "Krishnagiri", "Kanniyakumari", "Thoothukkudi", "Pudukkottai", "Nagapattinam", "Dharmapuri", "Ramanathapuram", "Sivagangai", "Thiruvarur");
      var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
      var marker;

      for (index = 0; index < districts.length; ++index) {

       //alert(districts[index]);



       geocoder.geocode({
        'address': districts[index]
       }, function(results, status) {
        //alert(districts[index]);
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
         //alert(index);
         var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
         var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
         //alert(latitude);
         //alert(longitude);

        }

        

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: {
          lat: latitude,
          lng: longitude
         },
         map: map,
         animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
         //labelContent: "chennai",
           // labelStyle: {opacity: 0.75},
         title: districts[index]
        });
        map.addListener('center_changed', function() {
         window.setTimeout(function() {
          map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
         }, 100);
        });

        marker.addListener('click', function() {
         map.setZoom(8);
         map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
         map.getBounds();
        });



       });



      }


     }
      function sleep(milliseconds) {
      var start = new Date().getTime();
      for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
       if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds) {
        break;
       }
      }
     }
   </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBIVqRDN8E_OEPcarzmz5mIJbyk25x424c&signed_in=true&callback=initMap" async defer>
    </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I get a javascript error with the posted code: `InvalidValueError: setPosition: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number`

Comment: What is this code for? `map.addListener('center_changed', function() {window.setTimeout(function() {map.panTo(marker.getPosition());}, 100);});`

Comment: <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBIVqRDN8E_OEPcarzmz5mIJbyk25x424c&signed_in=true&callback=initMap" async defer>  In this line you should enter your key instead of mine to run the script from your side.

Comment: Your `sleep` function is very annoying, it locks up the browser until the geocoding is done.

Comment: As is the function I asked about in the earlier comment which re-centers the map on the last marker to be geocoded once any of the markers are clicked.

Comment: map.addListener('center_changed', function() {window.setTimeout(function() {map.panTo(marker.getPosition());}, 100);});    This code is used to set the default position of displaying map.

Comment: I removed the function and tried. But same thing is happening.

Comment: That function continuously sets the center of the map to the position of a random marker (the last one successfully geocoded)  when you move the map.

Comment: Thank you so much geo. It works for me. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the map to center on the clicked marker, use `this` to refer to the marker inside the click listener:

```
marker.addListener('click', function() {
  map.setZoom(8);
  map.setCenter(this.getPosition());
  map.getBounds();
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle (but your code has lots of other issues)](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/exbx92rL/3/)